# How to add Java-Script properly in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have created a theme from the static website in wordpress. I want to know the right way to add javascript & style-sheet into the wordpress theme`s file. I have header.php, footer.php and index.php files and other css & javascript files that are linked in header.php.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Wordpress offers a function for that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 1):

Write following code into your theme's function.php file

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: I don`t have the function.php file. Then, What should I do?

Comment: What theme are you using? There should be a file with a set of common functions in it with whatever theme you've got.

Comment: Try putting this code into your header.php file before <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: The theme is made by me. And I have just split the my static website into header.php, index.php & footer.php

So, there is no function.php file and there is no <?php wp_head(); ?> in header.php

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add js and css in theme/front end than you cac add js and css in your `header.php` like this.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/your-js-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/your-style-sheet.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the scripts correctly in WordPress is incredibly easy. Below is surely an example code which you would paste inside your plugins file or inside your theme’s functions.php file to properly Load scripts in WordPress.

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
   wp_register_script('my_js', plugins_url('jsscript.js', __FILE__),  array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('my_js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts');
```

for stylesheets

```
function wpb_adding_styles() {
   wp_register_script('my_stylesheet', plugins_url('mystyle.css', __FILE__));
   wp_enqueue_script('my_stylesheet');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
```