# Adding scrollr in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm fairly new to wordpress and custom templates.

I'm trying to add parallax to a site I'm working on and want to use 'skrollr'.

I've downloaded it and have the skrollr.min.js file, which I've placed in my projects js/vendors/ directory.

What I'm trying to figure out in Wordpress is the proper way to add this to your project.

How do you typically add Jquery and other js libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Java-Script properly in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381417/how-to-add-java-script-properly-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include your js and jquery files into your wordpress by simply adding the code

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Just simply put your jquery file inside the assets/js folder. from there on use the path that your jquery file makes.

Enter the above code in your functions.php

That should include your above file in the wordpress.
If you further have any issues or problems let me know